Trying to create virtual mic with pulseaudio that survives reboot
So I'm trying to create a virtual mic with pulseaudio and I know how to do that and it works well but I'm trying to make it so that it survives reboot. I was looking up stuff about this and found a video that talked about how you can use the default.pa to do it but that hasn't worked and I assume I must of did something wrong but can't figure out what. I'm new to ubuntu and linux so any help is greatly appreciated. If you need me to provide anything else I gladly will.
